# How to measure the volatility of illiquid bond with no historical prices

Tags: volatility, fixed-income, risk, value-at-risk

The basket of corporate bonds that I am following barely traded after the issuance. Hence, there is no historical data to estimate the volatility. Can you suggest me a different approach to come up with a risk related measure. The market is really small and there are not many similar bonds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to matrix-price these bonds first. For each bond, either find a comparable bond or use your own judgment to determine the appropriate spread to a benchmark curve (e.g., OAS to LIBOR), then use the daily LIBOR curve and the corresponding OAS to obtain the daily prices.